# How to Convert query to JOIN

Tags: mysql

How can i convert below query to JOIN

```
UPDATE name_master 
SET 
    is_available = 'n',
    session_id = '18f05294fab50f30c13eea6304722376'
WHERE
    name_id IN (SELECT 
            *
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                nm.name_id
            FROM
                name_master AS nm
            JOIN product_master AS pm ON nm.name_id = pm.product_code
            WHERE
                nm.is_available = 'y'
                    AND nm.is_approval_needed = 'n'
                    AND nm.STATUS = 'active'
            LIMIT 1) AS t)
```

Comment: Can we just start again?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE name_master AS nm
    JOIN product_master AS pm ON nm.name_id = pm.product_code
SET 
    nm.is_available = 'n',
    nm.session_id = '18f05294fab50f30c13eea6304722376'
WHERE
    nm.is_available = 'y'
    AND nm.is_approval_needed = 'n'
    AND nm.STATUS = 'active'
```

I do not see any condition with columns from `product_master`. Is join itself enough criteria here?

Comment: product_master is only used here for JOIN,no other filters are required.

Comment: Query produces error as :  ERROR 1221 (HY000): Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it is forbidden to use `LIMIT` condition, where multiple tables are involved.

Comment: Then you need to somehow clearly specify **which** row you wish to update. `LIMIT` in "classic" update is imho merely a fool-proof precaution (in order to prevent damage to too many rows in badly constructed query).

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE nm
SET 
    is_available = 'n',
    session_id = '18f05294fab50f30c13eea6304722376'
FROM name_master nm
INNER JOIN
product_master pm 
ON nm.name_id = pm.product_code
WHERE
    nm.is_available = 'y'
    AND nm.is_approval_needed = 'n'
    AND nm.STATUS = 'active'
```

Comment: This is MSSQL's syntax.